# "Listening" for media key press events

Tags: keyboard, c++

I'm writing an application in C++ which needs to be able to listen for certain key presses as they occur in Linux, namely Media Next, Media Previous, and Media Play/Pause.

What APIs exist which will enable me to listen for keypresses? I assume that the enduser is running X, but if they're not, is there a "guaranteed™" way to catch the media key presses no matter what?

I'm a bit new to writing C++ and especially where it relates to Linux, but I'm in no way new to Linux (just getting used to living on bare metal).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to what extent you could do this globally under X using [Xlib event handlers](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/).  Sans X, I believe it will require a kernelspace component, which if you really really really wanted to do this, that might be the best bet.

However, **it's not a good idea.**  You did not say what you are trying to do, but I think it probably falls into one of two categories: either you want to use those keys to operate your app (case A) or you want your app to monitor the use of another application which uses those keys (case B).

In **case A**, it's not a good idea because associating global keystrokes with actions is the domain of window managers/desktop environments (the associations should be dynamic, not hard-coded), and when you decide to make up your own rules ignoring that fact, users and other developers are very unlikely to appreciate it.  If you want your app to respond to global key presses, you create client and server parts such that the client can be bound to a keypress by the window manager (as configured by the user), and then pass messages on to the daemon server.  You do not try and short-circuit or by-pass these existing conventions for no good reason (e.g., because it ostensibly makes your task easier or because you really want to hardcode certain particular keys).  You create an app that can be bound to whatever keys by the user via their window manager.

In **case B**, you are into even less friendly territory, because what you are essentially trying to do is create a [keylogger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keylogger).  And again, if you are really really determined to do this you might want to look around for a keylogging kernel module (pretty sure that's what it takes) to adapt, keeping in mind very few people are going to want to use software that has to resort to such (if it is just for you, that doesn't matter, but it is still probably a poor lesson in design).  Finally, if you are doing this because you are trying to introduce some external functionality into use of something that *you* associate with the use of various media keys, don't, because whatever that something is, it probably isn't hardcoded to those keys anyway: it's just a default of your window manager.

Comment: It's definitely case A, I'm writing a browser plugin which needs to capture media keys presses. With the variety of WMs out there (GNOME 3, GNOME 2, Gala, Unity, XFCE, awesome, Compiz, to name a few), how on earth could I possibly do this? Is there an implementation-independent way of doing this?

Comment: My application is a browser-based NPAPI plugin which simply emits JavaScript events when these keys are played, which has obvious practical use. Is there a framework I can use to make it easy to grab key events from the WM?

Comment: @TKKocheran : I haven't used NPAPI so I can't help you there; if the context is just for when the browser is the foregrounded app, ask an NPAPI question on SO -- the API must be portable across OS's anyway, right? [Or: netscape on linux uses GTK and there are event handlers there]. But if what you want to do is make it operable when the browser is not the foregrounded app, I think you are in the case A boat but slightly more complicated: you'd probably need to thread a server into the plugin so that it can listen for calls from a client that is associated with keys via the WM.